# First VS first time VS the first time VS at first VS for the first time

Tags: grammar

1. First when I saw you, I was afraid to talk to you.
2. When I first saw you, I was afraid to talk to you.
3. When I saw you first, I was afraid to talk you.
4. First time when I saw you, I was afraid to talk to you.
5. When I saw you first time, I was afraid to talk to you.
6. The first time when I saw you, I was afraid to talk to you.
7. The first time I saw you, I was afraid to talk to you.
8. When I saw you the first time, I was afraid to talk to you.
9. At first when I saw you, I was afraid to talk to you.
10. When I saw you at first, I was afraid to talk to you.
11. For the first time when I saw you, I was afraid to talk to you.
12. For the first time I saw you, I was afraid to talk to you.
13. When I saw you for the first time, I was afraid to talk to you.

Which ones are correct?

Answer (score 1):

1. **No** This sentence means something different.
2. **Yes**
3. **Yes**
4. **No** The word "when" is unnecessary, though it's a common mistake. There should also be the word "the" before "first".
5. **No** It needs to be "...the first time..."
6. **No** The word "when" is unnecessary, though it's a common mistake.
7. **Yes**
8. **Yes**
9. **Yes** although the meaning isn't exactly the same.
10. **Yes**
11. **No**. Neither "for" nor "when" are needed.
12. **No**, although "for the first time" is usable in other situations.
13. **Yes**.

Comment: "First I saw him on YouTube" Is this sentence right?

Comment: That isn't that simple. Please ask this as a separate question and explain what you think it means in the question